# Perform action before any type of request in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new to Django Rest Framework (and Django in general).

I have URL that look like this (this is an example, not the real URL):

`/api/v1/myapp/<param>/users/<user>/`

Were `<param>` is not coming from a model, but it is one of 3 possible constants I have defined somewhere in the code.

Somewhere else I defined a function that checks if the param is a valid one

    `def is_valid_param(param):
        ...`

Now in my REST views, before any kind of request, I would like to call `is_valid_param` and if it returns `False`, return a 404.

Is there a way to do this without repeating the same code in all the different view class methods that handle GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `CheckValidParamMixin` class which does this checking for you.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

class CheckValidParamMixin(object):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        param = self.kwargs.get('param')
        valid_param = is_valid_param(param)
        if valid_param:
            return super(CheckValidParamMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Invalid param')
```

**views.py**

```
class MyView(CheckValidParamMixin, ..):

    ...
    your code 
    ...
```

In your views, just inherit this mixin. This will provide the functionality of checking the param in any request if its a valid one.

If the param is found to be valid, it calls the super's `dispatch()` thereby generating proper response.
If the param is invalid, it returns a `HTTPResponseNotFound` response i.e `HTTPResponse` with a 404 status code.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to do this for a large set of views, you can do this in a middleware class. I would usually avoid this unless using mixins or decorators is a huge amount of work.

```
class CheckValidParamMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view, args, kwargs):
        if 'param' in kwargs and is_valid_param(kwargs['param']):
            raise Http404('invalid param')
        return None
```

Be sure to add this class to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` setting.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Since Django 1.10 there's a different way to write middleware, but the old one is still supported; see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware.